# Django - Support Multiple Login Mechanism

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-oauth

I've a Django Application which needs to support multiple login mechanisms ie, the default Django Authentication,  Phone Number(or some other Unique Identifier) OTP Authentication and should also support token mechanism.

I know all about how I can handle them individually (default username password, Django Oauth Toolkit, and making a separate Auth Backend for OTP), but don't know how to support multiple login mechanisms.

How can I achieve this? Any example will be highly appreciated.

PS:- I believe for each type of these authentication, we should be using the same default User Model.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/? You can create a custom provider if none meet your requirements: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#customizing-providers

Comment: Do not want to do a me too, but I would be interested as well. From my point of view, I would simply allow end user to select on UI which mechanism he/she wants to use for authentication and then have separate backends for each of them.

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar - Agreed. Different UI for a different mechanism. Since eventually, I would be wanting to keep all the users in the same User table, how would I generate OAuth tokens for each one of them. I'm just a little confused, how would I merge multiple libraries.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast May  I know what part of OAuth tokens is confusing? Also which libraries are we talking about?

Comment: https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/ and my own custom AuthBackend for OTP verification.

Comment: There is no need to merge any libraries in my opinion. Each AuthBackend will work independent of each other. Simply putting in my thoughts, I will allow user to select on login form his/her preference of mechanism. I will send that preference along with credentials. In the backend I can determine by preference what AuthBackend to use and thats it.

Comment: Correct. But then how do I generate a token for the users who logged in via OTP, so that the subsequent requests can be validated via tokens itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165944/discussion-between-rajesh-yogeshwar-and-pythonenthusiast).